# How to set which view expands in a UIStackView?

Tags: uistackview

[image]

I was just experimenting with UIStackView. In this quiz app i have different sized imaged, so i want the image to fill the space between the top button and the question text at the top. The buttons have constraints on them so they should be any size under 50px. As of now the top button is the one getting auto increased size, but that seems kinda random.

Answer (score 1):

According to what I understand you have all the items inside a vertical UIstack. The images have different sizes so the available space for the buttons will changes based on the size of the image. I suggest that you add constraints to all buttons to be equal in height. This way they will re-size based on the available space but they will all have the same height.